# Fatal error when I place class declarations outside of onCreate in android Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, logcat

I am new to android programming and I have the following in one of my activities.

I would like to declare the following

```
    AllJokes afrag = new AllJokes();
    OneLiners olfrag = new OneLiners();
    selectFragment sfrag = new selectFragment();
    RaceJokes rfrag = new RaceJokes();
    YoMammaJokes yfrag = new YoMammaJokes();
    LongJokes lfrag = new LongJokes();
    setContentView(R.layout.browse);
```

outside of the onCreate so that I may use it within the addalljokes method towards the bottom. This however causes the following error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.Ayman.jokeit, PID: 3685
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
            at java.lang.ref.FinalizerReference.<init>(FinalizerReference.java:42)
            at java.lang.ref.FinalizerReference.add(FinalizerReference.java:54)
            at android.os.StrictMode$InstanceTracker.<init>(StrictMode.java:2244)
            at android.os.StrictMode.trackActivity(StrictMode.java:1946)
            at android.app.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:760)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.BrowseActivity.<init>(BrowseActivity.java:11)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.selectFragment.<init>(selectFragment.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.BrowseActivity.<init>(BrowseActivity.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.selectFragment.<init>(selectFragment.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.BrowseActivity.<init>(BrowseActivity.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.selectFragment.<init>(selectFragment.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.BrowseActivity.<init>(BrowseActivity.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.selectFragment.<init>(selectFragment.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.BrowseActivity.<init>(BrowseActivity.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.selectFragment.<init>(selectFragment.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.BrowseActivity.<init>(BrowseActivity.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.selectFragment.<init>(selectFragment.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.BrowseActivity.<init>(BrowseActivity.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.selectFragment.<init>(selectFragment.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.BrowseActivity.<init>(BrowseActivity.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.selectFragment.<init>(selectFragment.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.BrowseActivity.<init>(BrowseActivity.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.selectFragment.<init>(selectFragment.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.BrowseActivity.<init>(BrowseActivity.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.selectFragment.<init>(selectFragment.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.BrowseActivity.<init>(BrowseActivity.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.selectFragment.<init>(selectFragment.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.BrowseActivity.<init>(BrowseActivity.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.selectFragment.<init>(selectFragment.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.BrowseActivity.<init>(BrowseActivity.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.selectFragment.<init>(selectFragment.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.BrowseActivity.<init>(BrowseActivity.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.selectFragment.<init>(selectFragment.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.BrowseActivity.<init>(BrowseActivity.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.selectFragment.<init>(selectFragment.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.BrowseActivity.<init>(BrowseActivity.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.selectFragment.<init>(selectFragment.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.BrowseActivity.<init>(BrowseActivity.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.selectFragment.<init>(selectFragment.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.BrowseActivity.<init>(BrowseActivity.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.selectFragment.<init>(selectFragment.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.BrowseActivity.<init>(BrowseActivity.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.selectFragment.<init>(selectFragment.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.BrowseActivity.<init>(BrowseActivity.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.selectFragment.<init>(selectFragment.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.BrowseActivity.<init>(BrowseActivity.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.selectFragment.<init>(selectFragment.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.BrowseActivity.<init>(BrowseActivity.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.selectFragment.<init>(selectFragment.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.BrowseActivity.<init>(BrowseActivity.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.selectFragment.<init>(selectFragment.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.BrowseActivity.<init>(BrowseActivity.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.selectFragment.<init>(selectFragment.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.BrowseActivity.<init>(BrowseActivity.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.selectFragment.<init>(selectFragment.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.BrowseActivity.<init>(BrowseActivity.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.selectFragment.<init>(selectFragment.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.BrowseActivity.<init>(BrowseActivity.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.selectFragment.<init>(selectFragment.java:14)
            at com.Ayman.jokeit.BrowseA
```

This is the Code within the activity

```
package com.Ayman.jokeit;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;


    public class BrowseActivity extends Activity{

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            AllJokes afrag = new AllJokes();
            OneLiners olfrag = new OneLiners();
            selectFragment sfrag = new selectFragment();
            RaceJokes rfrag = new RaceJokes();
            YoMammaJokes yfrag = new YoMammaJokes();
            LongJokes lfrag = new LongJokes();
            setContentView(R.layout.browse);

            //Creats object for fragments



            //steps for adding fragment to view
            FragmentManager smanager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction stransaction = smanager.beginTransaction();
            stransaction.add(R.id.browse_layout, sfrag, "selectFragment");
            stransaction.commit();


            //steps for adding fragment to view
            FragmentManager olmanager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction oltransaction = olmanager.beginTransaction();
            oltransaction.add(R.id.browse_layout, olfrag, "onelinerFragment");
            oltransaction.commit();
        }
        public void addAllJokes(){

        }

    }
```

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare them out side but initiate in `onCreate`:

Put outside `onCreate`

```
  AllJokes afrag;
    OneLiners olfrag;
    selectFragment sfrag ;
    RaceJokes rfrag;
    YoMammaJokes yfrag ;
    LongJokes lfrag ;
```

in `onCreate`

```
 afrag = new AllJokes();
olfrag = new OneLiners();
sfrag = new selectFragment();
rfrag = new RaceJokes();
yfrag = new YoMammaJokes();
lfrag = new LongJokes();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This fixed the issue. If you have spare time could you explain why it's necessary to initiate them inside onCreate?